# Find Geopoints for a Distance

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I see a lot of posts on finding the distance between two geopoints. I need to know how to find a geopoint that is such and such distance away (due West) from another geopoint, using Maps api V. 3. Is there a simple way? Or does one have to use the distance equation and solve for a geopoint? Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps API v3 [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) contains the computeOffset method:

computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number, radius?:number) | LatLng | Returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

If you want to do it in PHP the equations are available at:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Actually, the code from that site doesn't convert over to PHP readily.  Use http://www.cosmocode.de/en/blog/gohr/2010-06/29-calculate-a-destination-coordinate-based-on-distance-and-bearing-in-php instead; worked for me.